# Função $(document).ready() só executa uma vez

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma aplicação Asp.Net que possui um menu em uma tela principal que possui 2 links, cada um para uma página.

Quando eu clico no primeiro link e carrego a primeira página, a função `$(document).ready()` roda certinho e carrega todos os componentes que eu preciso.

Quando eu clico no segundo link, analisando passo a passo pelo Firebug, noto que a função `$(document).ready()` não é executada. Qual o motivo disso acontecer ?

Esta aplicação usa uma página de layout que é renderizada antes.

Função `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#spn').spinit({ min: 1, max: 100, stepInc: 1, pageInc: 10, height: 13, initValue: 95/*,callback: filtraModeloGrafico4*/});

    //Carrega o datepicker
    jQuery('#_InitialDateValue').datetimepicker( { format: 'd/m/Y H:i' } );
    jQuery('#_FinalDateValue').datetimepicker({ format: 'd/m/Y H:i' });

    jQuery('#_InitialDateValue2').datetimepicker({ format: 'd/m/Y H:i' });

    //Carrega a combo com os dias da semana
    $('#idComboTurno').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        nonSelectedText: 'Select a week day',
        nSelectedText: 'days',
        numberDisplayed: 0
    });

});
```

O nome do arquivo que tem a função `$(document).ready()` é `site.js`

Página que carrega tudo certo:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sequence Inspection - Graphics Report";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/site.js")

<div class="row-fluid">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="control-group span12">
         // Código...
         </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Página que não carrega a Função `$(document).ready()`

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sequence Inspection - Failure Report";
}

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/site.js")

<div class="row-fluid">
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportaExcel", "FailureReport", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
  //Código HTML
}
</div>
```

Comment: Os links são carregados por ajax, ou são requisições normais do browser?

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu carrego os links pelo helper do Asp.net por exemplo:  `<li class="span3">@Html.ActionLink("Graphics Report", "GraphicsReport", "GraphicsReport")</li> <li class="span3">@Html.ActionLink("Failure Report", "FailureReport", "FailureReport")</li>`

Comment: Vou deixar pra alguém que manja de ASP.Net responder, eu não sei o que esse helper gera, se está vinculado a algum js da Microsoft, etc.

Comment: @bfavaretto Exibindo o código fonte da página gerada temos  `<li class="span3"><a href="/GraphicsReport/GraphicsReport">Graphics Report</a></li>
<li class="span3"><a href="/FailureReport/FailureReport">Failure Report</a></li>`

Comment: Eu imaginei Emerson, mas não sei se tem algum script do MVC interceptando os cliques nesses links.

Comment: @bfavaretto O Helper gera um `<form>` em HTML puro mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é o caso, mas JS dentro de Partial normalmente não é executado.

Outra coisa que influencia é que você não especificou em que bloco de layout este JS será carregado. O correto é especificar `@section scripts`, que garante que o JS será carregado ao final de toda a renderização do layout:

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/site.js")
}
```

Comment: Cigano,segui suas orientações mas ainda não tinha funcionado. Antes eu tinha apenas um arquivo `.js` responsável por carregar as inicializações das duas páginas HTML que eu tinha. Resolvi então criar um arquivo `.js` para cada página HTML a ser carregada. Em cada arquivo `.js`, coloquei apenas as funções e inicializações de componentes referentes a sua respectiva página HTML.  Especifiquei as    `@section scripts` como você recomendou. Funcionou e notei que ficou até mais rápido. Obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: @Emerson De nada ;) Que ótimo que tudo funcionou bem. Precisando, só gritar.